# Xcode11 beta can't see standard library headers, but compile without problem

Tags: xcode, c++17

Xcode 11 with macOS Catalina finally could handle the filesystem support library which is critical for my project. To use this I've set the project's deployment target to 10.15, and set the language dialect to CNU++17, and the C++ standard library to the Compiler default.

For some reason when I write the code below the the editor, Xcode shows a bunch of error like: "Use of undeclared identifier 'std" or 'iostream file not found'. Nonetheless when I hit run, the code compile and run perfectly and does what it have to. The wierdest part is after build, only the first error message stays ('iostream file not found').

Is it something because of the beta, or I did something wrong? It's very annoying.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    std::string path = "/Users/hordon/Library/CloudStorage/iCloudDrive/Desktop/ferrilata-rosasite";
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}
```